# Using V-model on a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use `v-model` on `v-for` loop and its throwing an error.

How can i get this to work

```
<ul class="">
  <li class="" v-model="category.data" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
    <input :id="'checkbox'+ category.id" type="checkbox" @change="categoriesComputed($event)" :value="category.slug">
    <label :for="'checkbox'+ category.id">
      {{category.title | capitalize}}
      <span>{{category.job_posts | countObj | toNumber}} Jobs</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in Vue

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            type: [],
            categories: [],
            category: {
                data: [],
            },
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh magic crystal ball, say unto me this _"error"_ OP speaketh of

Comment: `categories` appears to be an empty array so it's unlikely anything in the `v-for` loop will be evaluated

Comment: Yeah ts populating the categories from an api end-point

Answer (score 1):

V-model only works if it’s being used on an input element or a custom component that emits a value event that supplies the value you want v-model to be updated with.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

https://jsfiddle.net/amcquistan/grq3qj36/

```
V-model is demo in this fiddle
```

Comment: Okay. So how can i get the dynamic checboxes to work??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use v-model in the `<input>` tags.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories: [
      { id: 1, slug: true, title: 'FOO', job_posts: 'Foo'},
      { id: 2, slug: false, title: 'BAR', job_posts: 'Bar'},
      { id: 3, slug: true, title: 'BAZ', job_posts: 'Baz'}
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="">
    <li class="" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
    <input 
      :id="'checkbox'+ category.id" 
      type="checkbox" 
      v-model="category.slug">
    <label :for="'checkbox'+ category.id">
      {{category.title}} {{category.slug}}
    </label>
    <input v-model="category.title"/>
  </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```